# mysql update visits=visits+1 bug

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a project in MVC, when I run this query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ads SET visits = visits+1 WHERE id = ".$ad->id);
```

from:

> localhost/advertise/

and MySQL works fine and adds 1 to visits field, but when I am using controller and method to see the page from:

> localhost/advertise/index/index

MySQL adds 2 to visits field but i traced my php code and the query was running only once
my tables type is innoDB and mysql version is 5.5.8

Is that a MySQL bug?

Comment: The most important rule to keep in mind: It is *never* a bug in the underlying system (especially not in the database server). It is always an error on your end. Exceptions to this rule are very few and very far apart.

Comment: Your code is running twice. That's a fact. You are loading the page two times or there's another `mysql_query` somewhere else. Also, you shouldn't call `localhost/advertise/index/index` to call a controller. Just `localhost/advertise/` should do to call the `index` method.

Comment: i know but i calling the localhost/advertise/categories/showads/5 and i saw the +2 result, my code doesn't running twice, i tracing that, i running a echo before all queries and i seeing only once result

Comment: Here's a test: If you request the URL with `wget` instead of your browser, does it count only +1? If so, something in your page triggers a duplicate request, like @Brad suggests.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your code is running when your browser makes a second request to your server, likely for favicon.ico or similar.

You can easily verify this.  Open up a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), and watch the requests go by.  No doubt you will see a second request.  Note that you likely won't see that second request in your browser's tools alone.  It often happens out-of-band from the requests for the page directly.

Comment: Opening the network tab in the browser console should already be enough, no need to install Wireshark.

Comment: @Tomalak, At least in Chrome, it doesn't show requests for favicon.ico.  I'm thinking that his routing is sending that request to his scripts.

Comment: It doesn't? Wow, I didn't know. Now that's stupid... In that case a real network sniffer is the better choice.

Comment: @Tomalak, Agreed.  :-D  But it makes sense in a way.  That network tab is isolated to the page being loaded.  Requests for other pages (or in this case, the browser "chrome" itself), are left out.  I often use Fiddler to narrow issues like this down.  I suggest Wireshark for those folks that don't use Windows.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. Didn't think about the sandbox the page is running in. (BTW Wireshark runs beautifully on Windows.)

Comment: when i viewing the source it's working fine and adding +1 to visits field but when i refreshing the real page(and no view-source) each time visits field is adding +2, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @mohammadfalahat, You can't solve the problem until you know what the problem is.  Use those tools I pointed out to figure out where the second request is.

Comment: thanks all, i found the problem, i forget to write full url in img src attribute, when i writed the full url in src the bug fixed.